# Pika Warning on Start Up due to Heartbeat Thread

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika

I am connecting to RabbitMQ using pika 1.1.0 and Python 2.7.
I am using a BlockingConnection and running a listener/consumer that will continually listen for messages from the queue. I am also creating a separate thread using the threading module that will send a heartbeat frame every 60 seconds to keep the running listener connected. The heartbeat sending code is:

```
blocking_connection._impl._send_frame(pika.frame.Heartbeat())
time.sleep(60)
```

Pika is logging a warning almost each time the listener starts up, saying 'WRITE indicated on fd=10, but writer callback is None;' This warning is printed from the file pika.adapters.utils.selector_ioloop_adapter.
But when I prevent the first heartbeat from being sent right away, meaning I put the 60 second sleep line before the frame sending line, the warning does not show up.

I am trying to understand what is actually happening, why does starting a consumer/listener and then a heartbeat thread right afterwards cause this warning? What is the significance and impact of the warning?

Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

> I am also creating a separate thread using the threading module that
> will send a heartbeat frame every 60 seconds to keep the running
> listener connected.

There is no need to do that. Pika will send heartbeats for you as long as your code does not block Pika's I/O loop. In addition, Pika is not thread-safe so calling `_send_frame` from another thread can cause errors like those you are seeing.

If you'd like, share your code on the [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) or [`pika-python`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/pika-python) mailing list and I will review it. I maintain the Pika library.